# nVidia fail after update

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I have a 64-bit computer with Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome and nVidia. I had the official drivers from nVidia installed, all working perfectly, even Steam games.

I did a reboot after a recent update and the next time I switched on the PC I found that after entering my password, the system hangs.

I tried then CTRL+ALT+F1 and when killing lightdm and doing startx I found this error (look at the screenshot).

[image: error at startx]

I can't understand why this update failed. Can't find anything googling just by looking for the error message.

I got also this log file when making "Xorg -configure". There is an error at the end.

```
 [   315.646] 
 X.Org X Server 1.15.1
 Release Date: 2014-04-13
 [   315.647] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
 [   315.647] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
 [   315.647] Current Operating System: Linux martin 3.11.0-20-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:32:49 UTC 2014 x86_64
 [   315.647] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=UUID=2718dd63-0056-4e1d-954b-d3c6d0b31b90 ro recovery nomodeset
 [   315.647] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
 [   315.648] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
 [   315.648] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
 [   315.648]   Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
 [   315.648] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
 [   315.649] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Aug 11 20:17:56 2014
 [   315.649] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f3e96be2d60
 [   315.649] (II) Module ABI versions:
 [   315.649]   X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
 [   315.649]   X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
 [   315.649]   X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
 [   315.649]   X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
 [   315.650] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0f00:1458:3544 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
 [   315.650] List of video drivers:
 [   315.651]   ati
 [   315.651]   sisusb
 [   315.651]   savage
 [   315.651]   r128
 [   315.651]   intel
 [   315.651]   mach64
 [   315.652]   radeon
 [   315.652]   modesetting
 [   315.652]   cirrus
 [   315.652]   s3
 [   315.652]   trident
 [   315.653]   openchrome
 [   315.653]   tdfx
 [   315.653]   qxl
 [   315.653]   mga
 [   315.653]   vboxvideo
 [   315.653]   siliconmotion
 [   315.654]   spiceqxl
 [   315.654]   neomagic
 [   315.654]   nvidia
 [   315.654]   sis
 [   315.654]   vesa
 [   315.654]   fbdev
 [   315.654] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
 [   315.655] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
 [   315.660] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.660]   compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
 [   315.660]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.660]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.660] (II) LoadModule: "sisusb"
 [   315.660] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sisusb_drv.so
 [   315.668] (II) Module sisusb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.668]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.9.6
 [   315.668]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.668]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.668] (II) LoadModule: "savage"
 [   315.668] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/savage_drv.so
 [   315.676] (II) Module savage: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.676]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.7
 [   315.676]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.676]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.676] (II) LoadModule: "r128"
 [   315.676] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
 [   315.689] (II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.689]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 6.9.2
 [   315.689]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.689]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.689] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
 [   315.689] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
 [   315.734] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.734]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.99.910
 [   315.734]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.734]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.734] (II) LoadModule: "mach64"
 [   315.734] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mach64_drv.so
 [   315.748] (II) Module mach64: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.748]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 6.9.4
 [   315.748]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.748]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.748] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
 [   315.748] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
 [   315.788] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.788]   compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
 [   315.788]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.788]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.788] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
 [   315.788] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
 [   315.800] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.800]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
 [   315.800]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.800]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.800] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus"
 [   315.801] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_drv.so
 [   315.806] (II) Module cirrus: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.806]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.5.2
 [   315.806]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.806]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.806] (II) LoadModule: "s3"
 [   315.806] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/s3_drv.so
 [   315.808] (II) Module s3: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.808]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.6.5
 [   315.808]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.808]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.808] (II) LoadModule: "trident"
 [   315.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/trident_drv.so
 [   315.820] (II) Module trident: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.820]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.3.6
 [   315.820]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.820]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.821] (II) LoadModule: "openchrome"
 [   315.821] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
 [   315.832] (II) Module openchrome: vendor="http://openchrome.org/"
 [   315.832]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.3.3
 [   315.832]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.832]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.832] (II) LoadModule: "tdfx"
 [   315.833] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/tdfx_drv.so
 [   315.842] (II) Module tdfx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.842]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.4.5
 [   315.842]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.842]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.842] (II) LoadModule: "qxl"
 [   315.842] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/qxl_drv.so
 [   315.855] (II) Module qxl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.855]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.1.1
 [   315.855]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.855]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.855] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
 [   315.855] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mga_drv.so
 [   315.869] (II) Module mga: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.869]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.6.3
 [   315.869]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.869]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.869] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
 [   315.869] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vboxvideo_drv.so
 [   315.881] (II) Module vboxvideo: vendor="Oracle Corporation"
 [   315.881]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.1
 [   315.881]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.881]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.881] (**) Load address of symbol "VBOXVIDEO" is 0x7f3e8ca8f460
 [   315.881] (II) LoadModule: "siliconmotion"
 [   315.881] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/siliconmotion_drv.so
 [   315.892] (II) Module siliconmotion: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   315.892]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.7.7
 [   315.892]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   315.892]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   315.893] (II) LoadModule: "spiceqxl"
 [   315.893] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/spiceqxl_drv.so
 [   316.008] (II) Module spiceqxl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.008]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.1.1
 [   316.008]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.008]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.008] (II) LoadModule: "neomagic"
 [   316.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/neomagic_drv.so
 [   316.019] (II) Module neomagic: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.019]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.2.8
 [   316.019]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.019]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.019] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
 [   316.019] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
 [   316.101] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
 [   316.101]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
 [   316.101]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.118] (II) LoadModule: "sis"
 [   316.118] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so
 [   316.138] (II) Module sis: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.138]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.10.7
 [   316.138]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.138]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.138] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
 [   316.138] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
 [   316.138] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.138]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
 [   316.138]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.138]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.138] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
 [   316.138] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
 [   316.140] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.140]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
 [   316.140]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [   316.140]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.140] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sisusb
 [   316.140] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
 [   316.140] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for cirrus
 [   316.140] (II) Loading sub module "cirrus_laguna"
 [   316.140] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus_laguna"
 [   316.140] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_laguna.so
 [   316.148] (II) Module cirrus_laguna: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.148]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.0
 [   316.148]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.148] (II) Loading sub module "cirrus_alpine"
 [   316.148] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus_alpine"
 [   316.148] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_alpine.so
 [   316.149] (II) Module cirrus_alpine: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [   316.149]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.0
 [   316.149]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for s3
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for trident
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for siliconmotion
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for spiceqxl
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for neomagic
 [   316.149] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.38  Wed Jan  8 18:51:00 PST 2014
 [   316.149] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
 [   316.149] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sis
 [   316.149] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
 [   316.149] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
 [   316.172] (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
 [   316.172] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
 [   316.172] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
 [   316.172] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
 [   316.172] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
 [   316.172] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
 [   316.172] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
 [   316.172] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
 [   316.172] (==) Automatically adding devices
 [   316.172] (==) Automatically enabling devices
 [   316.172] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
 [   316.172]   Entry deleted from font path.
 [   316.172] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
 [   316.172] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
 [   316.172] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
 [   316.172] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
 [   316.172] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
 [   316.172] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
 [   316.172] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
 [   316.172] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
 [   316.172] (EE) 
 [   316.173] (EE) Backtrace:
 [   316.173] (EE) 0: Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f3e9695ec78]
 [   316.173] (EE) 1: Xorg (0x7f3e967b6000+0x1ac969) [0x7f3e96962969]
 [   316.173] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3e958b3000+0x10340) [0x7f3e958c3340]
 [   316.174] (EE) 
 [   316.174] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
 [   316.174] (EE) 
 Fatal server error:
 [   316.174] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
 [   316.175] (EE) 
 [   316.175] (EE) 
 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
  for help. 
 [   316.176] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
 [   316.181] (EE)
```

I tried the steps at http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

The output for lspci was:

[image: Install verification]

And the output for the commands:

Glxinfo: Couldn't find the module

Modprobe -R nvidia: It returned nvidia_304

Modinfo nvidia_304: Couldn't find nvidia_304

Comment: try to install the nvidia-kernel package then modprobe nvidia or reboot. (not sure since I use arch)

Comment: Ok. I'm trying in just some minutes (I'm in Windows now and must reboot).

Comment: No way. The apt-cache doesn't show any "nvidia-kernel" package. The more global/generic ones are nvidia-common and nvidia-current. The "modprobe nvidia" shows the same error that you can see in the screenshot. :-(

Comment: take a look here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: I'm looking, but my error is not listed here. I enter my password and then the system hangs.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the 340 nvidia drivers and now a window appears asking me to report a problem but it does not matter which button I'm pressing. It hangs.

Comment: Log in rescue mode and remove Nvidia driver from loading and change xorg.conf

Comment: "Remove nvidia driver from loading"? Are you telling me to change the runlevel for one with only terminal? By the way, there was no xorg.conf but a xorg.conf.failsafe (or a similar name).

Comment: @vfbsilva I've been far from PC but I don't get yet what should I do. I know how to log in rescue mode, but don't know how to remove the driver from loading (something related with modprobe?). I don't know either what should I do with Xorg.conf because I don't have the file and don't know how to create one specificly for my graphical card.

Comment: modrobe -r nvidia will stop the driver from being loaded.

Comment: @vfbsilva I totally think it has nothing to do with xorg.conf. I copied a xorg.conf from the internet from a guy with the same graphical card. It didn't work. I also tried these days installing the official drivers from nVidia (340), but this time  not from repository. It asks me for the kernel source files, I made "apt-get install linux-source" and the install script keeps asking for the development source files for the kernel. All this time the screenshot error remains the same but with one change, now it says that the 340 module could not be found (before it said "331").

Comment: try the following: http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/
Also give me the output of step 5: 5. Verify the installation

Comment: @vfbsilva I did. I edited the main post so you can see the results up here. Now it's late here. Maybe tomorrow or wednesday I will try purging everything with apt-get purge nvidia* as it says at your link

Comment: Take a look here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099808 install the missing headers and give another try

Comment: @vfbsilva I almost surrender. I'm thinking about reinstalling now after trying all the things. Same error as always after doing all. The only clue I have is that when I install the linux-headers, it always installs the version 3.13.0-34 and doing uname it returns that my kernel is 3.11.0-20. Version numbers don't match and don't know if it's relevant. I think reinstalling all is my last and safe chance.

Comment: are you rebooting?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing now.

Comment: Howdid it went?

Comment: I tried again a few things but finally I reinstalled the OS. All this mess came to a point in which the easiest thing was reinstalling. Probably there were several errors all together creating this problem as consequence. It wasn't worth and I was losing my time and losing also your time. I have just finished and everything seems OK now. Thank you very very very much for your help.